# Error when creating Sales Order via Script for Fedex Ground

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

While I try to create sales order via Suitelet and give shipmethod or Ship Via field to Fedex Ground for Customers who are not in terms, it throws an error

```
 Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. The rate for this service is not available for the specified source and destination addresses.
    {
       type: "error.SuiteScriptError",
       name: "USER_ERROR",
       message: "Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. The rate for this service is not available for the specified source and destination addresses.",
       stack: [
          "anonymous(N/recordService)",
          "functionname(/SuiteApps/script name:line number)"
       ],
       cause: {
          type: "internal error",
          code: "USER_ERROR",
          details: "Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. The rate for this service is not available for the specified source and destination addresses.",
          userEvent: null,
          stackTrace: [
             "anonymous(N/recordService)",
             "functionname(/SuiteApps/script name:line number)"
          ],
          notifyOff: false
       },
       id: "",
       notifyOff: false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by “customers who are not if terms”? Usually I experience this error if customer address is not populated properly.

Comment: We use terms 30, terms 60 etc.. It just mean that customers whoa re in terms with us can pay later.
The address is entered correctly. When I change the customers to terms, the script works fine. But when I change customer back to no/nill terms , script throws an error

Comment: Instead of setting the terms to empty, why not set it to "Due on Receipt"?

Answer (score 0):

The shipping carrier you have opted for delivery is not able to calculate the real-time shipping cost for the customer's address, or it is also possible that the shipping carrier does not provide their services at customer's address. You can check by changing the customer's address. Also, you can check by choosing different shipping methods.

[image]